# create tree/XML structure from SQL query c#

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my current issue.  I need to display a tree like structure displaying a recall roster.  Our DBA created a stored procedure that returns [level],[name],[contact_info].

Example looks like:

```
[1] [test name1] [contact info]
[2] [sub to1] [contact info]
[3] [sub to2] [contact info]
[4] [sub to3] [contact info]
[3] [sub to2] [contact info]
[2] [sub to1] [contact info]
```

etc...

It's sorted in the order of the hierarchy

I haven't really worked with XML much but is that the way to go in loading/presenting this data.  Currently when I retrieving the data I'm returning it in a datatable.  There may also be a need to export this data to Excel.

Can anyone point me a good direction to go with this?

Comment: If you are getting the data from SQL Sever, then it can make the XML for you also.

Comment: What is the hierarchy of this data supposed to be determined?  How are parent/child relationships determined in the rows, I see no relation except in possibly the name and level but they're all duplicated.

Comment: @JeffMercado Without more info from the poster, my only guess is that the hierarchy is supposed to be derived from the order of the data (which, while possible, is a bad practice). So each row is the child of the first row above it that has `level=<mylevel>-1`

Comment: @ean5533: Ah that would make sense.  Definitely a bad idea.

Comment: @JeffMercado yes there is a extra field i didn't include that is a integer that is for sorting.  That's all I'm getting now from my DBA so that's what I have to work with.  Determining a child is if the next record is a level higher I know they are a child to the previous.  If the next level is lower then that user is a child to a previous user who's level will be one lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Do not trust in ANY data result order that you cannot stablish and manipulate. The "standar" way to retrieve data from a stored procedure is a datareader, datatable or dataset. You can even user Entity Framework to encapsulate the data. None of them ensures that the order is preserved. Assuming your resultset will be ordered is too risky.

2) Ask your DBA to include hierarchy informaion in the result (for example, a field with the key of the parent record)

3) Recursion works well for Hierarchy problems. Design your algorithm to start with a xml node and a bunch of top-level records. For each record: add a new xmlnode and make a recursive call passing the children of the record you just added.

4) If the expected result is small (lets say, a few hundreds of records) you can get all the data, store it in a datatable and use the Filter property to search for specific records. If the expected result is several thousand records, ask your DBA to create a store procedure to read one record's children and make a call to such procedure for each record in the xml node. Make sure you don't have loops in the data :)

Comment: guys thanks for all the input.  I ended up writing my own stored procedure gathering the fields I needs and then based my data off this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572721/recursive-treeview-in-asp-net