# Recursivity with panels in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a database with a table called "categories". The table has 3 columns: 
1. ID
2. Name
3. ParentID.

```
id | Name    |ParentID
_____________________
1  | John    | 0
2  | Charlie | 1
3  | Vasily  | 1
4  | David   | 2
5  | Edward  | 3
```

So John is the parent for Charlie and Vasily,  David is the child of Charlie and Edward is the child of Vasily.
The question is:
How can i create and populate some panels for each category, considering that the child panels must be inside their parent panels? The question is allmost the same as [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572721/recursive-treeview-in-asp-net) however i realy realy need it to be with panels instead of treeview.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried using a repeater?

Comment: Subclass Panel and add Parent and Children[] properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you should change the code as it is**

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id;
    public int ParentId;
    public string Name;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
        list.Add(new MyObject() { Id = 1, Name = "Alice", ParentId = 0 });
        list.Add(new MyObject() { Id = 2, Name = "Bob", ParentId = 1 });
        list.Add(new MyObject() { Id = 3, Name = "Charlie", ParentId = 1 });
        list.Add(new MyObject() { Id = 4, Name = "David", ParentId = 2 });

        BindTree(list, null);
    }
}

private void BindTree(IEnumerable<MyObject> list, Panel parentPanel)
{

    var nodes = list.Where(x => parentPanel == null ? x.ParentId == 0 : x.ParentId == int.Parse(parentPanel.ID));
    foreach (var node in nodes) {
        Panel newPanel = new Panel() { ID = node.Id.ToString() };
        if (parentPanel == null) {
            Panel1.Controls.Add(newPanel);
        } else {
            parentPanel.Controls.Add(newPanel);
        }
        BindTree(list, newPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aram Beginyan, thank You for reply, unfortunately there's an error when runnin the page: var nodes = list.Where(x => parentPanel == null ? x.ParentId == 0 : x.ParentId == int.Parse(parentPanel.ID)); That says: "[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]" How can it be solved?

Comment: int.Parse(parentPanel.ID) this will return error when ID is not int, check the ID type