# Stackoverflow exception - Recursive Treeview ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, recursion, treeview

I am trying to build a treeview recursively using VB.Net this is my code so far

```
.... Code to get the data table 

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        Dim oName As String = Nothing
        Dim pId As String = Nothing
        Dim cId As String = Nothing
        Dim cmts As String = Nothing
        Dim lvl As String = Nothing
        oName = row(0)
        pId = row(4)
        cId = row(5)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row(3).ToString()) Then
            cmts = row(3)
        End If
        lvl = row(2)

        list.Add(New MyObject() With { _
                                    .ObjectName = oName,
                                    .ParentId = pId,
                                    .ChildId = cId,
                                    .Comments = cmts,
                                    .level = lvl
                                })

    Next

BindTree(list, Nothing)

End Sub



Private Sub BindTree(list As IEnumerable(Of MyObject), parentNode As TreeNode)
    Dim nodes = list.Where(Function(x) If(parentNode Is Nothing, x.ParentId = "[Transform].[(Root)]", x.ParentId = parentNode.Value))
    For Each node As MyObject In nodes
        Dim newNode As New TreeNode(node.ObjectName, node.ParentId.ToString())
        If parentNode Is Nothing Then
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode)
        Else
            parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(newNode)
        End If
        BindTree(list, newNode)
    Next
End Sub
```

also the new class

```
Public Class MyObject
Public ObjectName As String
Public ParentId As String
Public ChildId As String
Public Comments As String
Public level As Integer
End Class
```

The issue I am having is that when this goes so far through the recursion I get a System.StackOverFlowException.  When looking at the exception snapshot every thing says "unable to evaluate expression" The error is coming from this line

`Dim nodes = list.Where(Function(x) If(parentNode Is Nothing, x.ParentId = "[Transform].[(Root)]", x.ParentId = parentNode.Value))` but Ive no idea why or how to resolve it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Try to call `BindTree(list, newNode)` inside else block.

Comment: @JorgeCalvoMorales the `BindTree(list, newNode)` is called regardless of being in or out of the else as its outside the if statement.

Comment: You must have a terminating condition where the method can return, usually if a node doesn't have child nodes, thus the recursion can be completed and won't fall to a no-infinity loop. That's why I suggested you move your call to the else block. You shouldn't call every time your recursive method, it must return.

Comment: @JorgeCalvoMorales I kind of see what you mean, but am so full of flu I cannot think correctly at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

A `StackOverflowException` isn't thrown by a particular line of code, that's just the first line of code in the method being called which is overflowing the stack.  And there isn't any more information that can really be given, because no further code can be executed.  (Because the stack is full.)

Your method is recursive:

```
Private Sub BindTree(list As IEnumerable(Of MyObject), parentNode As TreeNode)
    ' ...
    BindTree(list, newNode)
End Sub
```

Which is ok, except that you're not modifying the `list` variable anywhere.  So every time you call the method, you call it with the same `list`.  Therefore it will continue to perform the same logic, recursively, indefinitely, with no terminating condition.

Generally, you should think of a recursive method with the following structure (in VB-ish pseudo-code):

```
Method(ByVal something As SomeType)
    ' Check if the recursion should end
    If SomeTerminatingCondition Then
        Return
    End If

    ' Perform the logic for this step of the recursion
    DoSomething()

    ' Recurse again
    Method(somethingModified)
End Method
```

It's not *entirely* clear to me from the code how `list` should be modified.  But presumably when you call `BindTree(list, newNode)` at that point `list` should be some *subset* of the original `list`.

Comment: The list isnt being modified, I am trying to iterate through the list of and create a treeview

Comment: @SimonPrice: Yes, that's my point.  If you want to do this *recursively* then each iteration of the recursion needs to be given a subset or some modified version of the previous iteration.  Otherwise what will cause the recursion to terminate?

Comment: ok, ive not worked with recursion much in the past, how would be best to modify my code to acheive this?

Comment: @SimonPrice: This is where debugging is really going to give you the answer you're looking for.  Step through the code as it executes and examine the runtime values and behavior of each iteration of the recursive function.  It's possible that you don't want to modify `list` itself, but you *do* want to have some kind of terminating condition in the function.  The core of the problem is that you have an infinite recursion.  You need to find some logic by which it would know when to stop.  (In this case, to know when it has traversed the entire tree.)

Comment: i found a similar issue on another site, i need to remove the node or the from the list of nodes

Comment: using the example from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572721/recursive-treeview-in-asp-net as a reference this works straight off the screen so to speak without having to remove items from the list.  the differences I can see with this is that my parent node is a string not an int (not my choice, its just how the data has been given to me), so was wondering if there was anything you could see in my existing code that would cause my issue

Comment: @SimonPrice: Maybe you have bad data?  Do any of your nodes create an infinite loop with one another?  (Something like, A is parent of B, which is parent of C, which is parent of A?)