# Fill a list property with nested object content

Tags: c#, list, tree, nested

So I have a custom class RootElement, which currently is the final object that I transform into Json (using JsonSerializer). The terms have changed, and now I need it to be a flat list. The RootElement has a list of StartElements, and each following element is accessed with the Next-Property, creating a tree structure. How can I get these elements and put them into a List Property? Is there a way to do it with the getter of that property? I need to keep the order of the elements.
Not sure if code would be useful, I wouldn't know what do put here.

Comment: Why do you need a flat list?  Taking a tree structure and making it flat looses information.  If you do need a flat list then assign node numbers in flat list and add a parent/child column to flat list (node number of child and parent) so you can keep parent child relationships.

Comment: I think you're right. I don't need a flat list, but I do need a list of all the Elements that I get through the Next-Property, their properties can stay in parent child relationships. I just them to be on the same level in the Json output. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense.  The best way is to use a recursive method.  See following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572721/recursive-treeview-in-asp-net

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll have a look at that. I'll comment again if that doesn't help me.