# Display tree as navigation menu in View recursively ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this table:

```
Id  |  Name  |  Parent
------------------------
1   |  name1 |  null
2   |  name2 |  1
3   |  name3 |  1
4   |  name4 |  2
```

So the result would be:

```
|  name1  | 
---------------------
|  name2  |  name4  |
---------------------
|  name3  |
```

How do I pass this tree to `View` using recursion and how would it be displayed?

I checked other threads similar to my question, but none had a complete answer. Thanks

Comment: Check this out: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-TreeView-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ already checked that out. What if I have more than 1 subcategory? I can't create unlimited tables for obvious reasons.

Comment: In that case you must have a collection of  `MyClass` as a property which defines the children for each one. E.g:  `public ICollection<MyClass> MyClassChildren { get; set; }`. Once done you'll have to create the `TreeView` recursively. This may help: https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/05/17/build-ui-tree-with-recursive-asp-net-core-view-component/

Comment: Another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572721/recursive-treeview-in-asp-net